# Using updateMany() in updating multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have trouble in updating all my documents in MongoDB. Update is the easiest I could do but I still wanted options on how to update them all without using update all over again. as you can see in the picture only one document is modified not all of them. should I use `foreach`? and If yes, how to do it?
I apologize in advance since I'm only a beginner, still learning the ropes of MongoDB.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
db.employees.updateMany(`

{id: 1},{$push: {"contact": {"email": "steve.badiola.gov.ph", "phone": "+1 1234567"}}},

{id: 2},{$push: {"contact": {"email": "jamir.garcia.gov.ph", "phone": "+2 1234567"}}},

{id: 3},{$push: {"contact": {"email": "reg.rubio.gov.ph", "phone": "+3 1234567"}}},

{id: 4},{$push: {"contact": {"email": "ian.tayao.gov.ph", "phone": "+4 1234567"}}})
```

Comment: [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) updates multiple documents on the base of single query condition, you are doing bulk update try [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html)

Comment: hi, but our instructions go like this. Update all the document by adding a sub-document named “contact” with a key-value, “email”: “name@gov.ph” (Example: steve.badiola@gov.ph) and “phone”: “+1 1234567” (note: +1 value should depend on their rank number).

Comment: you have to use forEach with updateOne() or bulkWrite().